# How to loop after 'Except ERROR' line in Python

Tags: python, loops

as part of the Chapter 3 exercise for Automate the Boring Stuff, I need to write a short program that mimics the Collatz sequence, where:

- If number inputted is even number, divide it by 2, repeat until it equals 1;
- If number inputted is odd number, multiply it by 3 then plus 1, repeat until it equals 1;
- Create a clean exit for Ctrl+C.
- Detect whether the user    typed in a noninteger string.

Below is my code so far, which seems to work but I would appreciate any advice/best practice for improving it.

**My main question is, after the program prints 'Enter integers only', is there any short and simple way to loop back to the 'Enter any number: ' line?** I can't think of anything atm besides complicated if loops. Thanks.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0 :
        results = number // 2
        print(results)
        if results != 1:
            collatz(results)
    elif number % 2 == 1 :
        results = 3 * number + 1
        print(results)
        if results != 1:
            collatz(results)

try: 
    entry = input('Enter any number : ')
    number = int(entry)
    print(number)
    collatz(number)
except ValueError:
    print('Enter integers only.')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.end()
```

Comment: Warning: DO NOT use a recursive function when calculating Collatz numbers: given the right number, you'd get _millions_ or recursion. Just try with 27 :)

Comment: Which part of it is a recursive function? I tried 27 with the code and it seems to work fine and not too many lines. Sorry I'm a beginner so can't really tell.

Comment: I suggested 27 because it takes more than one hundred steps to be solved, which can be surprising for such a small number. But there are larger numbers which literally require millions of steps, so you will get a "recursion depth exceeded" error. Your function is recursive because it calls itself - that's what recursion means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `while loop`. The below code will be helpful for you.

```py
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0 :
        results = number // 2
        print(results)
        if results != 1:
            collatz(results)
    elif number % 2 == 1 :
        results = 3 * number + 1
        print(results)
        if results != 1:
            collatz(results)

while True:
    try: 
        entry = input('Enter any number : ')
        number = int(entry)
        print(number)
        collatz(number)
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter integers only.')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break # Stop the while loop.
        sys.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to keep prompting the same, until the program exits. I'd suggest just encapsulating the program code in a while(true) loop:

```
while True:
    try: 
        entry = input('Enter any number : ')
        number = int(entry)
        print(number)
        collatz(number)
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter integers only.')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.end()
```

Comment: just quick sidenote, `true` shouldn't be in brackets and should have a capitalised "t".

Comment: @AnonyMous woops, thanks for the heads-up. It's still early here :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a "while" loop.

```
while True:
    try:
        ...
    except:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an iteration to make sure the input is integer type.

```
while True: # executes the loop body indefinitely
    try: 
        entry = input('Enter any number : ')
        number = int(entry)
        print(number)
        collatz(number)
        break  # immediately terminates the loop entirely
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter integers only.')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.end()
```